# htaccess redirect / remove characters from the middle of urls / cut ending and put it in the begining

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect, url-rewriting

We are having a htaccess redirect problem, hoping to receive a solution. We need to redirect urls (generated mostly after internal search returns) similar to:

```
domain.com/pretty-much-any-char-1/.../pretty-much-any-char-N/?folder=fr
domain.com/pretty-much-any-char-1/.../pretty-much-any-char-N/?folder=es
domain.com/pretty-much-any-char-1/.../pretty-much-any-char-N/?folder=cn
domain.com/pretty-much-any-char-1/.../pretty-much-any-char-N/?folder=pt
domain.com/pretty-much-any-char-1/.../pretty-much-any-char-N/?folder=ja
```

to

```
domain.com/fr/pretty-much-any-char-1/.../pretty-much-any-char-N/
domain.com/es/pretty-much-any-char-1/.../pretty-much-any-char-N/
domain.com/cn/pretty-much-any-char-1/.../pretty-much-any-char-N/
domain.com/pt/pretty-much-any-char-1/.../pretty-much-any-char-N/
domain.com/ja/pretty-much-any-char-1/.../pretty-much-any-char-N/
```

It would be noteworthy to let you know that we also have the following rule already in .htaccess:

```
RewriteRule ^(fr|es|cn|pt|ja)/(.*) $2?folder=$1 [L,QSA,NC]
```

Thanks for your time!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} folder=(.*)$
RewriteRule ^domain.com(.*)$ domain.com/%1$1?
RewriteRule ^(fr|es|cn|pt|ja)/(.*) $2?folder=$1 [L,QSA,NC]
```

Edit:

```
RewriteRule ^(?:www\.)?domain.com(.*)$ www.domain.com/%1$1?
```

That one works for "www.domain.com" and "domain.com"

Comment: Thanks a lot for your quick response! I did try your solution. However, it didn't work. It would be possible that I have not properly explained the question, or I might be missing something!

Comment: @1453939 can you give me a full link from your website and post your htaccess?